# Struts property in external file

Tags: java, properties, struts, struts-config

I have been having this issue for a long time now and i can't seem to find an answer. I want to know if at least that is possible.
I have a Web application and in this action i want to upload an `.xls` file. The issue is I don't want to upload a big file and I put this constraint in the `struts.xml` :

```
<action name=....
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"> 
        <param name="maximumSize">2097152</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
</action>
```

What I want to know is if somebody knows of any way to externalize this value from struts.xml. Today, a fully loaded .xls file exceeds 2 MB.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: any specific reason you want to externalize these?

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi - so in the future i can only change the property in the property file and not recreate the `.war` of my application